# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm pretty sure my random forest model is working. When I look at the predictions made, and the actual classes in the test set, they match up pretty well. The first part is me encoding the categorical data:

```
Y_train[Y_train == 'Blue'] = 0.0
Y_train[Y_train == 'Green'] = 1.0
Y_test[Y_test == 'Blue'] = 0.0
Y_test[Y_test == 'Green'] = 1.0

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50)
rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = rf.predict(X_test)

for i in range(len(predictions)):
    predictions[i] = predictions[i].round()

print(predictions)
print(Y_test)

print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, predictions))
```

When I run this code, I successfully get the `predictions` and `Y_test` printed:

```
[1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.
 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.
 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.
 0. 0. 0. 0.]
615    1
821    1
874    1
403    0
956    1
      ..
932    1
449    0
339    0
191    0
361    0
Name: Colour, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

As you can see, they match up perfectly, so the model is working. The problem I have is the last part when I try and use the `confusion_matrix()` function in scikit-learn, I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Work\Colours.py", line 101, in <module>
    Main()
  File "G:\Work\Colours.py", line 34, in Main
    RandForest(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
  File "G:\Work\Colours.py", line 97, in RandForest
    print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, predictions))
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 253, in confusion_matrix
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 81, in _check_targets
    "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets
```

What can I do to either of the datasets so that the `confusion_matrix()` function doesn't throw any type errors?

EDIT - `predictions` and `Y_test` are both the same shape, `(100,)`

Comment: don't use `0.0` and `1.0`. For example do: `Y_train[Y_train == 'Blue'] = 0` or  just `Y_train = Y_train == 'Green'`

Comment: @QuangHoang didn't fix the problem, thanks though :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare matrices with the same dimention, so if predictions contains a matrix of 1 column and 850 rows (for example), Y_test must be a matrix of 1 column and 850 rows.

print(confusion_matrix(Y_test[1], predictions))

Comment: I get a `KeyError: 1` when I do this.

Comment: The shape of both `Y_test` and `predictions` is `(100,)`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by encoding the categorical data like this instead:

```
for i in range(len(Y_train)):
    if Y_train.iloc[i] == 'Blue':
        Y_train.iloc[i] = 0.0
    else:
        Y_train.iloc[i] = 1.0

for i in range(len(Y_test)):
    if Y_test.iloc[i] == 'Blue':
        Y_test.iloc[i] = 0.0
    else:
        Y_test.iloc[i] = 1.0
```

If someone could tell me why this fixed the problem that would be helpful.

**EDIT - I've found the real reason I was having problems. I'm using the Regressor model instead of the Classification Model. Stupid mistake. This can all be avoided by using `RandomForestClassifier()` instead of `RandomForestRegressor()`.**